# Define AutomationPeer

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing my own interactive Control derived class and I have stumbled upon AutomationPeer. I have read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/ui-automation-of-a-wpf-custom-control) at MSDN and it looks like a lot of work for something without an immediate benefit. I can't seem to find anything about it in the book "Pro WPF 4.5", which makes me think it is probably a not so important topic.

Can I get into trouble if I omit the definition of an AutomationPeer for my own Control class?

Comment: It is technically possible, whether your program needs to be usable by a user with visual impairments is a matter of law.  In the USA the ADA (Americans with Disabilities Act) applies.  That's something that Microsoft needs to worry about a great deal.  Whether it applies to small software vendors is murky, they don't seem very worried about it.  Ask a lawyer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the common controls of the framework have their own AutomationPeer which allow you to see some properties. You can check this properties using 
[Visual UI Automation Verify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/jj160544(v=vs.85).aspx) or the [Inspect tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx).

Both of these tools are available in the [Windows Software Development Kit](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) (you just need to select the *Debugging Tools* during the setup).

If you create a custom control, according what you want to be able to test in it, you will have to implement your own AutomationPeer if the properties of your parent control are not enough.

You can find a sample code here: [UI Automation with WPF](https://wpftutorial.net/UIAutomation.html).